# How to track web requests in IIS 7.5

Tags: windows, iis-7.5

Is it possible to see the web requests made within IIS?  I've seen references to clicking the "Failed requests tracing" but I cannot see that in the server's IIS dialog that I'm working with.

Is this an extra feature you need to install perhaps?  I've tried to check within the turn windows features on or off but on the server it doesn't produce the familiar dialog that lists an array of features with checkboxes.  Instead it launches the Server manage window.

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks

[image: IIS version screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open IIS Manager and root of the left side tree is selected (Your server name). You must be see **Worker Processes** Icon:
[image]
after you click it see all worker processes per your sites. click one of them that you want and see their requests.